# How can I make the section of a prolate ellipse like the one shown in the figure?

Tags: modeling

The left ventricle of the heart has a prolate ellipse geometry. The thickness of the wall of the ellipse has several layers. To describe these layers, it is necessary to make a section of the ellipse wall. It would be great to do it in Blender. I appreciate the help for teaching cardiovascular medicine.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could do it this way:

- Create a cube, subdivide it 3 times and in the *Operator* box give it a *Smoothness* value of 1:

[image]

- Cut the top half, scale on the Z axis:

[image]

- Cut a hole:

[image]

- Extrude all along the normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]

- Create some edge loop, both to sharp the edge and to give it different colors:

[image]

- Give it the colors, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Superlative thanks.